# React hooks state in single useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use new React hooks capabilities, but stumbled a bit.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nidu/8fs7govr/1/)

I have a `useEffect` which calls `setInterval`, which updates local state. Like this:

```js
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const k = setInterval(() => {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(k);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>Counter via state: {counter}<br/></div>
  );
```

It doesn't work right, because counter is captured on first call and so counter is stuck at `1` value.

If i use refs, ref is updated, but rerender is not called (will only see 0 value in UI):

```js
  const counterRef = React.useRef(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const k = setInterval(() => {
      counterRef.current += 1;
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(k);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>Counter via ref: {counterRef.current}</div>
  );
```

I can make what i want by combining them, but it really doesn't look right:

```js
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  const counterRef = React.useRef(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const k = setInterval(() => {
        setCounter(counterRef.current + 1);
      counterRef.current += 1;
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(k);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>Counter via both: {counter}</div>
  );
```

Could you please tell who to handle such cases properly with hooks?

Comment: @estus yeah, turns out it's duplicate. My initial problem doesn't contain setInterval and here i added it just to make a simple example, but eventually problem is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useRef` is useful only in cases when component update is not desirable. But the problem with accessing current state in asynchronous `useEffect` can be fixed with same recipe, i.e. using object reference instead of immutable state:

```
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ counter: 0 });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const k = setInterval(() => {
        state.counter++;
        setCounter(state);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(k);
  }, []);
```

The use of mutable state is discouraged in React community because it has more downsides than immutable state.

As with `setState` in class components, state updater function can be used to get current state during state update:

```
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const k = setInterval(() => {
        setCounter(conter => counter + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(k);
  }, []);
```

Alternatively, `setTimeout` can be used to set new interval every second:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const k = setTimeout(() => {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(k);
  }, [counter]);
```

Comment: Missed this in the docs, my bad. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I have found myself in this situation a couple times by now, and my prefered solution is to use `useReducer` instead of `useState`, like so:

```js
  const [counter, dispatch] = React.useReducer((state = 0, action) => {
    // better declared outside of the component
    if (action.type === 'add') return state + 1
    return state
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const k = setInterval(() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'add' });
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(k);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>Counter via state: {counter}<br/></div>
  );
```

Although is adds a bit of boilerplate, it really simplifies the "when is my variable taken in account ?".
More here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Comment: The solution is very neat! It's honestly hard to decide which answer is more spot on. It may become more unwieldy however if i need to update multiple states there, but i guess with `setState(function)` it would be pretty much the same.

Comment: @nidu IIRC, `useState` uses `useReducer` internally, the former is no-nonsense way to update state, while the latter is Redux-like. Pick one that suits your style.